# Why regex extract return wrong value in scala

Tags: java, regex, scala

```
val pattern = "[A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{4}".r
val extractedData =  pattern.findFirstIn("find ABCD1234")
```

I have the above code to look for valid data.

**Input:**

```
find DTD0001
```

**Expected Output:**

```
DTD0001
```

**Input:**

```
find ABCD1234
```

**Expected Output:**

i.e. nothing.

Currently, it is returning **BCD1234** which is incorrect.

I want to make it return value only when it has 3 letters + 4 digits. otherwise don't return any value. How to make this correct?

Comment: May I know how to do that?

Comment: it returns nothing after I enter the correct string as **DTD0001**

Comment: You really should update your Input sections based on your comments below. A reasonable person would see an input of `ABCD1234` and make a regex from that when your actual input contains more characters before the "ABCD1234" like "find ABCD1234" and likely other examples. Your presented examples should be as close to real examples as possible to get the best answer and not waste people's time.

Comment: The input section is updated by others. I have just corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findFirstIn()` returns the first sub-string that matches the pattern. If you don't want a sub-string, but just to test for a match, then that's not the tool you want to use.

```
scala> "ABCE1234" matches "[A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{4}"
res5: Boolean = false

scala> "ABC1234" matches "[A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{4}"
res6: Boolean = true
```

---

If you want to extract a matching word from a longer string then you need to incorporate the word boundaries into your pattern.

```
scala> val pattern = "\\b[A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{4}\\b".r
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = \b[A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{4}\b

scala> val extractedData = pattern.findFirstIn("find ABCD1234")
extractedData: Option[String] = None

scala> val extractedData = pattern.findFirstIn("find ABC1234")
extractedData: Option[String] = Some(ABC1234)
```

Comment: But this one seems like not checking the whole string (if I have a sentence). I need to get the String when it is **true**. Is there any ways to do it?

Comment: if I have a sentence like "find abc1234" it will be wrong.

Comment: If you have a whole sentence you will want go back to findFirstIn, but anchor at word boundaries.

Comment: Yeah !!! Adding the word boundaries will get expected result. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

Based on the following conversation with the OP:

> if the sentence is "find ABCD1234", I would like to check the
> "ABCD1234" if it matches the regex or not. Else, it will return
> nothing. I am not expect it will help to trim the word and return the
> correct substring
>
> @KenChe - Do you mean, you want to return `true` for `DTD0001` and `false` for `find ABCD1234`?
>
> if true i would like to get the string, else return empty string

If you want to match the whole string, you can use [`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) to return the matched string; otherwise, a blank string.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String[] testStrings = { "find ABCD1234", "DTD0001" };
        for (String s : testStrings) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + getMatchComb(s));
        }
    }

    static String getMatchComb(String textString) {
        return textString.matches("[A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{4}") ? textString : "";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
find ABCD1234 => 
DTD0001 => DTD0001
```

If you want to match the first substring, you can use [`Matcher#find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) as shown below:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String[] testStrings = { "find ABCD1234", "find ABC1234", "find ABC12345", "find ABC1234 DTD0001 ABCD1234",
                "DTD0001" };
        for (String s : testStrings) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + getMatchComb(s));
        }
    }

    static String getMatchComb(String textString) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{4}\\b").matcher(textString);
        return matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : "";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
find ABCD1234 => 
find ABC1234 => ABC1234
find ABC12345 => 
find ABC1234 DTD0001 ABCD1234 => ABC1234
DTD0001 => DTD0001
```

Note that `\b` is used for [word boundary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).

### Original answer:

I do not know [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) but since you have also tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java), given below is a solution using Java:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String[] testStrings = { "find ABCD1234", "DTD0001" };
        for (String s : testStrings) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + getMatchComb(s));
        }
    }

    static String getMatchComb(String textString) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{4}").matcher(textString);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            sb.append(matcher.group());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
find ABCD1234 => ABC1234
DTD0001 => DTD0001
```

Note that I have used the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/fIzlVd/1), `[A-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{4}` in which there is an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Learn more about Java regex API at **[Lesson: Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)**

**`Stream` version:**

```
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                    "find ABCD1234",
                    "DTD0001"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " => " + getMatchComb(s)));
    
    }
    static String getMatchComb(String textString) {
        return Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{4}")
                .matcher(textString)
                .results()
                .map(MatchResult::group)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
find ABCD1234 => ABC1234
DTD0001 => DTD0001
```

Comment: if the sentence is "find ABCD1234", I would like to check the "ABCD1234" if it matches the regex or not. Else, it will return nothing. I am not expect it will help to trim the word and return the correct substring

Comment: @KenChe - Do you mean, you want to return `true` for `DTD0001` and `false` for `find ABCD1234`?

Comment: if true i would like to get the string, else return empty string

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer. Your answer will work if the person is looking for java